# C# - Change DbContext ConnectionString after Auth

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to make an application that changes the DbConnection string based on the authenticated user.

So, after the user login,  I have to get that user, see a field like "connectionName" and look for that connectionString on my app.config to connect to my database.

I already know how to set my Dependency Injection to pass the constructor params, but how do I get at my dependency injector Project the logged user ?

Something like this.

This is in a Project called "Project.Infra"

DBContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    //ConnectionStringBasedOnUserLogged will be a propertie on my userModel
    //so I have to get the logged user before have it.
    public MyDbContext(string ConnectionStringBasedOnUserLogged)
        : base(ConnectionStringBasedOnUserLogged)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    //DbSets...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    //Mappings...
    }
}
```

This is in a Project called "Project.Infra"

Repository

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private MyDbContext _ctx;

    public MyRepository(MyDbContextcontext)
    {
        this._ctx = context;
    }

    //Implementation of interface...
}
```

This is in a Project called "Project.Api"

Controller

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    private IMyRepository _repo;

    public MyController(IMyRepository repo)
    {
        this._repo = repo;
    }
    //Implementation
}
```

This is in a Project called "Project.Startup"´

DepencyInjection

```
public static class DependencyResolver
{
    public static void Resolve(UnityContainer container)
    {
        //How do I get here some details about the logged user at my application ?
        container.RegisterType<MyDbContext, MyDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor("HereWillComeTheConnection"));
        container.RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());        }
}
```

Comment: Why not use factory pattern. Create a DbContextFactory that will be able to create your DbContext with the appropriate connection string based on authenticated user.

Comment: Agree with Nkosi. Then I think you can inject the `DbContextFactory` instead of `DbContext`.

Comment: I've tried it, but I can't access my user data by "User.Identity"...

I'll have to cache my information or something like it.

Comment: @Nkosi, can you guys provide an example of how to implement it?